# How to check Tendoo CMS version

Tags: php, content-management-system, codeigniter-3

How do you check the version of this codeigniter app 
 (Tendoo CMS)?

https://github.com/Blair2004/tendoo-cms

Answer (score 0):

Using composer you can check like this

`composer show tendoo/cms`

It will show its version and all dependencies this package requires.